# Video editing software for software development

Tags: linux, software-development, video-editing

I've used [ScreenFlow](https://www.telestream.net/screenflow/overview.htm?__c=1) on a Mac for many years.  As a software developer it is useful to record my screen.  Then immediately drop into a simple video editor.  I typically cut video, freeze frames, add text, add images and sometimes remove audio.

I don't think I'm going to get a combination screen recordor/editor as powerful as this anywhere else.  Can you recommend an editor that can take a screen recording and provide some/most/all of the features above on Linux?  (Specifically Elementary os which is based on Ubuntu):

Some of the options I've found:

Avidemux (website looks clunky for a design based tool)
Cinelerra
Kdenlive
Kino
Lives
Open Broadcaster Software (I've used this to stream video games.  Haven't tried it as a video editor)
Simple screen recorder
Blender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Screenrecording: Kazam**

Kazam is pretty easy to handle but quite powerful for a simple screen recorder. You can record a single Window, the whole Screen or a predefined area. You can set a timer when the Recording should start. The best thing: It just works!

It does not come with any video editing.

**Simple Video Editing: OpenShot**

I have made good experience with OpenShot although I never did much video edititng. It has all the basic functionality for a video editor like you requested:

- Cut Video
- Freeze Frames
- Add Text
- Add Images
- Remove Audio (of course add Audio too)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. However, OOB these products have some issues on a HiDPI monitor.   Not usable at the time of this writing on HiDPI

Answer (score 0):

For recording on my Linux desktops I use gtkRecordMyDesktop.  Saves in Ogg format.

For editing, I've only used old versions of Premier with Wine (way old, like version 5.0 from 2000-ish) and I've played with kdenlive but not in many moons.